# Javascript login bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, forms, bookmarklet

Using Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 m

I'm making a bookmarklet for work to speed up user log in. The environment I need to access has multiple different logins that I need to use frequently, so instead of logging out, typing in my credentials and logging back in, I made a bookmarklet to speed it up a little.

```
javascript:  
    (
        function getCreds(){
            var username = prompt("Please enter username details before the @ symbol.", "user.name");

            un.value = username + "@example.com";  
            pw.value = "password";  

        }
    )();
```

All users have user names like test1@exmaple.com, test2@example.com and test.test@example.com. They all end in @example.com. The password is the same for every test user. This makes it so I just type in "test" and the javascript does the rest.

To speed this up further I would like it make it automatically login when you click OK on my prompt.

I tried `loginForm.submit();` and many variations but I get a 401 error.

I cannot just write my own login form in the bookmarklet like many examples I've found have because there are built in javascript functions and library calls on the page I am using.

Can I inject the user name and password into the `value` fields of a form and then submit the form without making a custom html form?

Comment: Open the console, go to Network and watch the different requests (both manual and bookmarklet), compare and see what differs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
To submit form generate click event on submit button: `submitButton.click();`